# VBA Copying Cell Range To Range on Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub foo2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("pathoffile.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("pathoffile.xlsm")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("Main").Range("AH5:AH994").Value = x.Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B991")

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

My code is as follows. I'm trying to copy a range of data from one workbook and place it onto another. I cannot get this working over a range of data. For instance, if I provide the range AH5:AH994 for sheet y, and a single range B2 for sheet x, it will run and populate the range with the data from B2. Is it possible to grab the whole range, B2:B991 and copy it to AH5:AH994, given they're the same size?

Comment: I'd add the missing `.Value` on the end of `.Range("B2:B991")`... otherwise that should work.

Comment: If you just want to work with `Range("B2")`, you can `Resize` it to the same number of rows and columns as `Range("AH5:AH994")`.

Comment: @BigBen Was not aware I needed the .Value tag, works now. Appreciate it! Because I can't accept your comment as an answer, I will accept the other answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x.Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B991").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("Main").Range("AH5:AH994")
```

or if you only want values:

```
x.Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B991").Copy 
y.Sheets("Main").Range("AH5:AH994").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

but value transfer should work and avoids the clipboard:

```
y.Sheets("Main").Range("AH5:AH994").Value = x.Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B991").Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solutions, BigBen's comment solved my issue, but I will mark this answer for others who may have a similar issue.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me adding value transfer as a potential option here. That way future readers know to use it and avoid the clipboard.

Comment: I agree that BigBens answer is better, but also I had actually thought that using the copy method with the Destination parameter avoided using the clipboard, but upon testing it this it actually appears to clear the clipboard...weird

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Column Range to Another Workbook

**Setup**

- In one workbook is the source data in column `B`, starting in the 2nd row (cell `B2`). The number of rows will be calculated at run-time.
- The goal is to copy the data (values only) to the column range starting in cell `AH5` in another workbook.

**Result**

- After calculation e.g. `sRng = .Range("B2:B5")`, `tCell = .Range("AH5")` the values can be copied like this:

  ```
  tCell.Resize(sRng.Rows.Count).Value = sRng.Value
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ValuesFromRangeToFirstCell()
    
    Const sFirstCell As String = "B2"
    Const tFirstCell As String = "AH5"
    
    Dim src As Workbook
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("pathoffile.xlsx")
    With src.Sheets("Database")
        ' Define Source Column Number.
        Dim sColumn As Long
        sColumn = .Range(sFirstCell).Column
        ' Define Source Last Row Number.
        Dim sLastRow As Long
        sLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Define Source Column Range.
        Dim sRng As Range
        Set sRng = .Range(sFirstCell, .Cells(sLastRow, sColumn))
    End With
    
    Dim tgt As Workbook
    Set tgt = Workbooks.Open("pathoffile.xlsm")
    With tgt.Sheets("Main")
        ' Define Target First Cell Range.
        Dim tCell As Range
        Set tCell = .Range(tFirstCell)
    End With
    
    ' Copy values from Source Column Range to Target Column Range.
    tCell.Resize(sRng.Rows.Count).Value = sRng.Value
    
    src.Close

End Sub
```